# What is an overall term for a service that publishes digital publications?

Tags: phrase-requests, hypernyms, computing

I'm looking at what I am calling Digital Edition Solution Providers (ways of taking a PDF of a magazine and turning it into a website, and content for sale on Apple Newsstand, Android, KindleFire etc.), and trying to compare them.

But the term "Digital Edition Solution Provider" is one I came up with on my own because I didn't know what these things were called in general.

Any idea what these are called generally?

Comment: What is your definition of digital publication ?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be more than one term.

The most generic name for things like the iTunes store and Android Market are "Digital Media Service" and "Digital Content Provider." There doesn't appear to be an exact consensus on a universal generic term for this.

For those which specialize in making content digital, the term "digitization" is also used, so you will come across "Digitization Services" for example, but these are usually distinct from things like iTunes.

Comment: +1 for DCP. (not that the rest of the answer isn't solid as well)

Comment: I think content providers are 'creators of content' and this is different from the service of 'digitizing'. Digital publishing services or DMS is better, as Dougvj above.

Answer (score 1):

*Digital publishing platform* fits, as in this sentence in [a trade publication](http://www.mediabiznet.com.au/news/home.do?newsId=5074): "The launch of Apple's digital publishing platform iOS5 Newsstand signals a new focus and support for publishers taking their content to the iPad." From [a library journal](http://www.libraries.wright.edu/noshelfrequired/2011/09/21/bookriff-a-new-digital-publishing-platform-to-go-live-this-month/): "Bookriff, yet another digital publishing platform, will soon go live. Yet while it is entering a crowded field, this one is worth a close look as it has the potential to take hold."

The term also works for a service that moves content online.  One [company](http://www.pageturnpro.com/self-service-solution.aspx) touts a "Self-Service Digital Publishing Platform" that permits a user to convert a PDF "add unique features and embed your publication on your website."

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking one format (PDF) and turning it into another format (a website [HTML?]), you could use the term *digital conversion service* or *data conversion service*.